# Dynamically rotate image according to distance from mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css-animations

I have an image, and want to rotate it.  However, I don't think css keyframes will work because they can't be dynamically changed.  I am currently using a jquery plugin called jquery rotate at http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com.  What I want to do is change the speed of rotation by the distance from the element to the mouse.  Are there any solutions that are not too CPU intensive (hopefully), because jquery rotate is already pretty wasteful of CPU power.  Here is my code:

```
    var angle = 0;
    var distance = 200;
    setInterval(function () {
        plus = distance / 100;
        angle -= plus;
        $("#elem").rotate(angle);
     }, 25);
```

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eCV8q/) jsFiddle which rotates the image 2 degrees each loop.  What I would like to do is speed up the rotation as the mouse gets closer (by changing the "distance" variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : updated the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eCV8q/25/

---

Find the mouseX & Y in the body with body.pageX & Y then find the offset of your image using element.offset().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    // had to put the image in a container div as it was rotating
    var offset = $('#container').offset(); 
    var distanceX = e.pageX - (offset.left + ($('#elem').width()/2));    
    var distanceY = e.pageY - (offset.top + ($('#elem').height()/2)); 
}
```

Comment: yes, that is great but how do I use this to vary the speed of the rotation, for some reason, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eCV8q/24/) doesn't work.

Comment: The interval function needs to be outside the mousemove function, otherwise it will be calling the interval function all the time. I've moved it outside and updated the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eCV8q/25/

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly, even on an old emac with 256MB of RAM, and a 1GHz proccessor!

Comment: Is there anyway this code can be modified to work with the opposite effect? so the closer you get to the image the quicker it spins? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes as it can dynamically generate and apply css keyframes to elements on the fly.

I have used it for a similar purpose as you have described where the pupils of a pair of eyes followed the mouse around the page. Awesome :)